# How to move data from an array to the buffer when a program starts?

Tags: c, visual-studio, testing, syntax

Is there a way to have the data in an array of characters or integers to be placed in the buffer when the programs starts as if the user has entered this data?

For example:

```
int main()
{
    int run = 1;
    char a[] = "4\nasdfg\0";
    char in = NULL;

    datatobuffer(a);//is there a command for this in C?

    while (run){
        in = getchar();
        if (in == '\0')
            run = 0;
    }
    //loop stopped, user didn't do anything
}
```

Alternatively, is there a way to do this in the debugger of VS?

This is for testing several functions that rely on user input so I want to automate the process of entering data.

EDIT: not optimal but I guess I'll do it with a different macro program, although it isn't really a practical solution for more then a few dozen of characters since it's slow.

Comment: You mean you want to keep data in `stdin` buffer? why not go for command line arguments?

Comment: I don't think I know what stdin buffer is, but I want to have data in the buffer immediately when the program starts as if the user has entered this data. @Gopi

Comment: Do you mean command line in windows? @Gopi

Comment: '\0' has the value 0 so you dont need the if statement inside the while loop

Comment: @Anton.P that doesn't really matter since it isn't the point of this question. This code is just an example.